# Three.js - anomaly with shadow casting

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow

I have this code:

```
  var other_phongMaterial   = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xf455f4 });      
  var other_sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 50, 50), other_phongMaterial );
  var other_cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200), other_phongMaterial );

  var phongMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xcccccc });
  var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 50, 50), phongMaterial );
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200), phongMaterial );


  sphere.castShadow = true;
  cube.receiveShadow = true;
  other_sphere.castShadow = true;
  other_cube.receiveShadow = true;

  sphere.position.set(0,250,-130);
  other_cube.position.set(0,50,-150);

  other_sphere.position.set(0,250,130);
  cube.position.set(0,50,150);

  scene.add(cube);
  scene.add(sphere);
  scene.add(other_sphere);
  scene.add(other_cube);    

  var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );
  spotLight.position.set( 100, 1000, 100 );

  spotLight.castShadow = true;
  spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
  spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;

  spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 500;
  spotLight.shadowCameraFar = 4000;
  spotLight.shadowCameraFov = 30;

  scene.add( spotLight );
```

And, I can't understand why the shadow casting works only on one. I noticed the following things:
- If I try to exchange the cubes, the shadow will cast on one, but still not on the other.
- if I use the same material as other_cube, it will work, meaning that as it is written now like this works for me, instead if I use two different materials it will cast only on other_cube.
But the setup of these shapes is completely equal! so.. I can't figure out, really.. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It's possible that there are other anomalies I didn't remember to put, so please tell me in every case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your other_cube is not inside the shadow camera frustum. You should be able to see the shadow camera dimensions by setting `spotLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;`. Only objects inside that cone will get shadows computed. Then move the cube or adjust the shadow camera properties accordingly. Shadows can be  bit tricky, and the problem could be something else entirely. But I'd start by checking that.

Comment: Sorry, it's not that, I think. During development I keep it always, here is removed to put as little code as possible. And in some condition shadows work, so I think the problem is in the variables, in references, or something like that.